# SQL Server - Best practice to circumvent large IN (...) clause (>40000 items)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm developing an ASP.NET app that analyzes Excel files uploaded by user. The files contain various data about customers (one row = one customer), the key field is `CustomerCode`. Basically the data comes in form of `DataTable` object.

At some point I need to get information about the specified customers from SQL and compare it to what user uploaded. I'm doing it the following way:

1. Make a comma-separated list of customers from `CustomerCode` column: `'Customer1','Customer2',...'CustomerN'`.
2. Pass this string to SQL query `IN (...)` clause and execute it.

This was working okay until I ran into `The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan` exception when trying to pass ~40000 items inside `IN (...)` clause.

The trivial ways seems to:

1. Replace `IN (...)` with `= 'SomeCustomerCode'` in query template.
2. Execute this query 40000 times for each `CustomerCode`.
3. Do `DataTable.Merge` 40000 times.

Is there any better way to work this problem around?

**Note:** I can't do `IN (SELECT CustomerCode FROM ... WHERE SomeConditions)` because the data comes from Excel files and thus cannot be queried from DB.

Comment: Can you not create a temporary table and join it to your main table?

Comment: Yeah, thought about that too. But in this case I need to insert 40000 rows into it either by making another large `INSERT` query (won't it fail as well?) or executing `INSERT` 40000 times.

Comment: How usable is the *result* produced by generating this final table from 40000 inputs? Also SQL Server has OLE DB providers that can read Excel files, if it's feasible to place the file somewhere the database server can read them, so "from Excel files and thus cannot be queried from DB." is incorrect.

Comment: Well, I have ~50 SQL-query templates in the app and do all Excel processing C#-side. I'm having the problem only with this one query so processing Excel SQL-side *exclusively* for this case would be problematic (aligning access right, storing the file somewhere etc.)

Answer (score 1):

["Table valued parameters"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) would be worth investigating, which let you pass in (usually via a `DataTable` on the C# side) multiple rows - the downside is that you need to formally declare and name the data shape on the SQL server first.

Alternatively, though: you could use `SqlBulkCopy` to throw the rows into a staging table, and then just `JOIN` to that table. If you have parallel callers, you will need some kind of session identifier on the row to distinguish between concurrent uses (and: don't forget to remove your session's data afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't process too many records at once, because of errors as you mentioned, and it is such a big batch that it takes too much time to run and you can't do anything in parallel. You shouldn't process only 1 record at a time either, because then the overhead of the SQL server communication will be too big. Choose something in the middle, process eg. 10000 records at a time. You can even parallelize the processing, you can start running the SQL for the next 10000 in the background while you are processing the previous 10000 batch.